# Ajax Multiple Callbacks is not working for first callback?

Tags: 8, forms, hooks, ajax, taxonomy-terms

I have been trying to load the data to other select list field from the first select list callback.

I want to change the two select list variables based on the first select list on changes, please refer the below sample code for understanding.

```
function example_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
     $form['field_example']['widget']['#ajax'] = [
      'callback' => 'example_ajax_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'example-company-wrapper',
      'event' => 'change',
      'progress' => [
        'type' => 'throbber',
        'message' => t(''),
      ],
    ];

function example_ajax_callback(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $first_callback = example_company_form_trigger(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state);
  $second_callback = example_company2_form_trigger($first_callback, $form_state);
  return $second_callback;
}

function example_company_form_trigger(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
return $form['field_example1'];
}

function example_company2_form_trigger(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
return $form['field_company2'];
}
```

When the ajax callback is calling, the second callback (example_company2_form_trigger ) is only working, the first callback(example_company_form_trigger) is not working.

I am facing this issue while returning the form.

Could anyone please help me to sort out this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need multiple ajax callbacks, you need multiple ajax commands.

First wrap each form element in a separate div container and then return for each one an ajax command from the same callback:

```
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\ReplaceCommand;

...

  function example_ajax_callback(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $response = new AjaxResponse();
    $response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand('#example-wrapper1', $form['field_example1']));
    $response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand('#example-wrapper2', $form['field_example2']));
    return $response;
  }
```